# Using BIND framework for two way data-binding in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to use BIND framework to bind a UITableView with UITextfield's which can edit the content.

I'm trying to achieve something very similar to how binding is done in Mac OSX. Bind a datasource with view, let the user make changes, on save the data is saved after validations.

Typically this is done by subscribing the delegate or observing the `valueChanged` event from textfield. I wanted to try out a new way to reduce this, that's how I came across [BIND framework](https://github.com/markohlebar/BIND).

It encourages to use an MVVM framework, usually seen in .NET. Binding is as simple as mapping the keypath of model with the view component. But I'm finding it difficult to achieve to two way binding, from model to component and back.

```
BINDINGS(MHPersonNameViewModel,
         BINDViewModel(name, ~>, textLabel.text),
         BINDViewModel(ID, ~>, detailTextLabel.text),
         nil);
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, and not even really an answer to your question, but I hope it's still useful.

Take a look at https://github.com/mutech/aka-ios-beacon. This is a binding framework that integrates into Interface Builder and (by default) uses the view controller as root view model.

You don't have to write any code to initialize bindings. In your example, assuming that the view controller has (KVO compliant) properties "name" and "ID", you would just need to set the UILabel "text binding" properties to name and ID (you find the in the property panel in interface builder and enable bindings for the view controller (also in the properties panel).

And that should be all you have to do to establish bindings.

In versions up to 0.1.1 of AKABeacon, "enable bindings" is not yet there. In this case your view controller would have to inherit from AKAFormViewController.